# LaTeX \tableofcontents add custom line with custom pointer

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

In my LaTeX document, after `\begin{document}` I have `\tableofcontents`. However, later in the document, I have `\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}]{mypdf.pdf}`. I want to create a new "invisible section", that is, a section that appears in the table of contents as a normal section but just redirects to the first page of that `\includepdf`, which would be Page 3.

Is there any way to add a custom entry into the TOC that links to a certain page (if you're wondering, I do have `hyperref` loaded).

Thank you!

Here's a sample doc (pretty much all I have):

```
% preamble stuff
\begin{document}
% \toc command:
\tableofcontents
% more random stuff
% ...
\chapter{sample}
\section{random} 
blah blah
% here is where I want a new section to be in the TOC, 
% but not actually show up as a section with all of the bold/large font and stuff
% as this is a PDF document foreign to latex:
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}]{mypdf.pdf}
% So the TOC section should point to the first page of mypdf.pdf, 
% which would be Page 3.
```

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE! It is customary to go ahead and show what you tried.  So go ahead and post your complete minimum working example, a "WME"...even if it doesn't work :)

Comment: @AFeldman I don't really have a working example or such (what's a WME?) but I posted my sample doc if that wokrs

Comment: Can you complete your code to make it a proper minimal document? We want something we can copy-paste and compile so it should start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` if you are using LaTeX.

Comment: Oops, replaced all 13's with 3's; I somehow typoed up the first time and then kept that typo with me...?

Comment: Also sorry @cfr, my actual document has a bunch of filler text in between places so I couldn't copy it here; next time I'll try to make a working document sample ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic method:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ch}
\section{sec} text
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{xsec}
\includepdf{mypages}
\end{document}
```

[image: extra section]

Obviously if you want a numbered section etc. that needs to be specified. However, that really wouldn't make sense, so hopefully that's not what you want.